# error with else statement in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, list-comprehension

I was playing around with list comprehension but I get an syntax error with the else statement

```
doctor = ['house', 'cuddy', 'chase', 'thirteen', 'wilson'] 
first = [doc[0] for doc in doctor if doc[0] == 'h' else doc[3]]
```

What's the problem with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code

```
doc[0] for doc in doctor if doc[0] == 'h' else doc[3]
```

roughly translates to

```
for doc in doctor
    if doc[0] == 'h'
        doc[0]
else doc[3]
```

Hence the else part has no definition of `doc`. The correct code is

```
first = [doc[0] if doc[0] == 'h' else doc[3] for doc in doctor]
```

of which

```
doc[0] if doc[0] == 'h' else doc[3]
```

is a ternary condition based on each iterated value of `doc`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
doctor = ['house', 'cuddy', 'chase', 'thirteen', 'wilson'] 
first = [doc[0] if doc[0] == 'h' else doc[3] for doc in doctor]
```